# Why do double quotes from the url get escaped into php?

Tags: php, url

I am GETting the url `test.php?value=%22hello%22` and when I print out the value it shows `\"hello\"` and `$_REQUEST['value'][0]` is `\`. Why? How do I fix this (correctly)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on. You should:

- Upgrade to PHP 5.4 *or*
- [disable them](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) in your PHP configuration file *or*
- disable them in your Apache configuration (same link) *or*
- (last resort) test to see if they are turned on and then run [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes) over the input.

Comment: Huh, that sucks (i cant change server configuration, so I now have to use `php.ini`'s). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't guarantee the environment to allow reconfiguration, you could use this reusable code to recursively dig through $_GET, $_POST arrays and clean them up with stripslashes:

```
class de_slasher {

    function recursive_stripslashes($a) {
        $b = array();
        foreach( $a as $k => $v ) {
            $k = stripslashes($k);
            if( is_array($v) ) {
                $b[$k] = $this->recursive_stripslashes($v);
            } else {
                $b[$k] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
        return($b);
    }

    function check_and_fix_magic_quotes( &$array ) {
        if( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
            $array = $this->recursive_stripslashes( $array );
        }
    }

    function __construct( $auto = false ) {
        if( $auto === true ) {
            $this->check_and_fix_magic_quotes( $_POST );
            $this->check_and_fix_magic_quotes( $_GET );
        }
    }
}
```

To use, simply include the class, and invoke `$slasher = new de_slasher(true);` to automatically clean up $_GET and $_POST. This only happens if magic quotes setting is on. If you instantiate the class without the 'true' parameter, then you can selectively deep-filter any array:

```
$my_array = array( "name" => "Herbert\'s Apple" );
$slasher = new de_slasher();
$slasher->check_and_fix_magic_quotes( $my_array );
```